# Unrecognized option 'c copy'

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have been working on a script as a part of both learning process and creating handy tools. I am trying to loop over a list of video files to extract a certain part of each video on the list. By looking at example scripts and ffmpeg documentation I finally came up with this:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess as sp

from moviepy.tools import subprocess_call

def ffmpeg_extract_pandomim_subclip():

    with open('videolist.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

    for video in lines:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(video)
        targetname = "%s-pandomim%s" % (name, ext)
        t1 = "00:10:00"
        t2 = "00:15:00"
        cmd = ["ffmpeg",
               "-i", "%s%s" % (name, ext),
               "-ss", t1,
               "-to", t2, "-c copy", targetname]

        subprocess_call(cmd)

ffmpeg_extract_pandomim_subclip()
```

I know this is not the ideal way to do it: I created a videolist.txt and listed all the video file names in that txt file, line by line,(T1-1.mp4, T1-2.mp4,... ) that share the same folder with the python script "new 1.py" and the actual videos which are T1-1.mp4, T1-2.mp4,...

The error I am getting really confuses me because when I use -c copy from cmd it works just fine.

The full error is:

```
C:\Users\çomak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:/ffmpeg/bin/new 1.py"

[MoviePy] Running:
>>> ffmpeg -i T1-1.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:15:00 -c copy T1-1-pandomim.mp4
[MoviePy] This command returned an error !Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ffmpeg/bin/new 1.py", line 28, in <module>
    ffmpeg_extract_pandomim_subclip()
  File "C:/ffmpeg/bin/new 1.py", line 25, in ffmpeg_extract_pandomim_subclip
    subprocess_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\çomak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 48, in subprocess_call
    raise IOError(err.decode('utf8'))
OSError: ffmpeg version N-83975-g6c4665d Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavcodec     57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavformat    57. 66.104 / 57. 66.104
  libavdevice    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavfilter     6. 76.100 /  6. 76.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Unrecognized option 'c copy'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using Pycharm and if I remove the -c copy part it works, but the process is slow... With -c copy, it is much faster.

I appreciate your time and effort to help me out!

Comment: Can you try expanding this to the two individual parameters they are: `"-c", "copy"`?

Comment: That's amazing!! Thanks a lot Mr. Clark. I will keep that detail in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be due to the way that [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) actually invokes the command; you can not condense all of your commands into a single string, they should be fully expanded.

To fix this, simply expand it to the two parameters that they are

```
[ ..., "-c", "copy", ... ]
```